# Joint two array to one array?

Tags: python

a:

```
[[1,2,3],
 [4,5,6]]
```

b:

```
[[7,8,9],
 [10,11,12]]
```

How can I get an array like:

```
[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]
```

using a and b?

Comment: Like this `c = [a, b]`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [python's append method](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html):

```
x = []
x.append(a)
x.append(b)
```

Or in short (mentioned by @Kasramvd in the comments):

```
x = [a, b]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the append over empty list to add as many list as you want. See below example.

```
>>> final_list = []
>>> a = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6]]
>>> b = [[7,8,9], [10,11,12]]
>>> final_list.append(a)
>>> final_list.append(b)
>>> final_list
[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by other answers, if you want `[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]]`, call `append` or simply write `c = [a, b]`.

However, the title reads "**Joint** two array to one array?", so I suppose what you actually expect is `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],[10,11,12]]`, which seems more useful. To do this, call `extend` like this:

```
x = []
x.extend(a)
x.extend(b)
```